# How can I dump the memory of a process in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory, process, dump

Are there any tools to dump the running application from memory in Windows 7?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just "right click" the process in the taskmanager and select "create memory dump"

[image]

Comment: can i still be able to run that file?

Comment: @abmv: "run" as in .. start the dump? or do you ask if the dumping process stops the process? if it is the latter: dumping the memory does not stop the process.

Comment: well i'm looking for something like PROCDUMP32

Comment: @abmv: well, that is not what you asked for in the first place. a good tool for reverse engineering is "ida pro" (http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro).

Comment: i guess the word dump was misleading thanks for you reply

Comment: Do note that you can only do this on Windows 6.x variants (Win7/Vista/2008).  Win5.x cannot do this without [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from SysInternals.

Comment: yep, but thats what OP wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is probably [`procdump`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) from SysInternals.

The [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) gives more advanced options (e.g. automatically dump the process on certain conditions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adplus -crash -p <process id> -o <place to put the dump>` from command line if the process you want to dump is crashing at some point. see [here](http://kb.acronis.com/content/15505)