# How to dump the memory of a process to a file and then restore the process into memory?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, restore, dump

I have a game where saving is impossible most of the time, there are big gaps between saves and many progress is lost if the game crashes or I die.

I want to know if it's possible to dump the RAM of a process onto the disk and then restore it when needed? and if yes, how do I do that?

Just like suspending a VM-Ware virtual machine... but not a virtual machine yet a process in windows.

Comment: Sort of related: http://superuser.com/questions/133938/how-can-i-dump-the-memory-of-a-process-in-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: @Gizmo - Unless the software supports this feature its not possible to do this.  An application's memory space is protected.

Comment: invalid duplicate - I want for WINDOWS, "duplicate" wants for LINUX

Comment: and I know how I can dump using task manager, but I want to restore that dump into memory..

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to do that. See my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/904441/possible-to-save-process-as-dump-file-to-disk-and-then-reload-the-process-later/978777#978777