# Possible to save process as dump file to disk and then reload the process later?

Tags: windows-7, memory, process, dump

Is it possible to save process as dump file to disk and then reload the process later?

For example if I'm using a video editing program and are in the middle of rendering a file, then I can go to the Resource Monitor in windows and right click the processes and "Suspend Process" a.k.a pause the program then later I can right click and "Resume Process" that works fine because everything is still in memory  , but is there a way were I can "Suspend Process" then save the memory to disk using like a dump file then restart my computer and load that dump file back into memory and resume the process from were it left of.

If you go into the windows task manager and right-click the process > "Create Dump File" is there a way to load that back in or is the dump file only made for debugging?

(I'm using windows 7 64bit)

Answer (score 2):

The dump file you can make that way is only for debugging. It does not have enough information to re-create a process.

Particular things that aren't there would be anything the process has written to the pagefile, plus RAM pages that are on the standby or modified list. None of that will persist through a reboot, which was part of your objective. (It won't even persist once the process is gone.)

Another major problem with this sort of idea is that if any of the files being used by the process happen to be deleted or altered while the process is "checkpointed" it will likely crash. Whole-system sleep or hibernate works because the whole system is not running and so can't modify its disk files (unless of course you thwart this by booting a different OS and use it to modify the disk).